# Правильность кода начинающего

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

С точки зрения правил и стандарта, правилен ли мой код?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter please x: ");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int answer = (int)(x * x + Math.Sin(x + 1)) / (x - 2);
        Console.WriteLine(answer);

        firstOne();
        secondOne();
    }

    public static void firstOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter please x: ");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int answer = (int)(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(x, 4) + Math.Sqrt(Math.Abs(x + 1))));
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }

    public static void secondOne()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter please a: ");
        int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Enter please b: ");
        int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int answer = (((int)Math.Pow(a, 2)) + ((int)Math.Pow(b, 2))) / (1 - (((int)Math.Pow(a, 3)) - b) / 3);
        Console.WriteLine(answer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Здесь есть [специальный подраздел для ревью кода](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ничего плохого не вижу. Я бы только возводил в степень последовательным умножением (или там дважды умножением на себя). Плюс первые 4 строчки `Main` стоит выделить в отдельную процедуру.

Comment: Да, и процедуры названы от фонаря, это плохо.

Comment: @free_ze, по ссылке только на английском, на ruSO также возможно задавать вопросы по инспекции кода, [удовлетворяющие следующим требованиям](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review)

Comment: Ещё, с точки зрения английского языка `"Enter please a: "` неверно. Please пишется или в начале, или в конце через запятую.

Comment: @VladD, может тогда еще ввод/вывод и работу с данными разделить?

Comment: @Grundy: Для такого игрушечного примера, думаю, оверкилл. Если код вырастет, тогда, несомненно, надо будет, но для конкретно этого кода на мой вкус рановато и overdesign.

Comment: @VladD, тогда уж и первую часть вынести в функцию, чтобы было однообразно :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Я пожаловался на то, что первые четыре строчки не выделены в процедуру потому, что код выглядит неравномерно: кусок кода не оформлен в процедуру, а два других аналогичных куска оформлены.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40320/discussion-between-grundy-and-vladd).

Comment: @Grundy: Ага, я писал об этом в комментарии выше.

Comment: @Grundy Почему вас смущает английский на профессиональном ресурсе? Single responsibility - это то, что нам нужно.

Comment: @free_ze, если бы все было так просто, не было бы нужды в ruSO и других региональных сообществах :)

Comment: @Grundy У код-ревью аналогов на русском нет. Ну г***окод.ру если только рассматривать) Считайте мой комментарий советом.

Comment: Про выделении вначале в отдельную процедуру. Можно подробнее пожалуйста?

Comment: @free_ze, _Считайте мой комментарий советом._ - какой из? и каким советом?

Comment: По оформлению кода советую прочитать https://rsdn.ru/article/mag/200401/codestyle.XML

Comment: @Grundy Самый первый. Самым добрым)

Answer (score 4):

1. В C# обычно методы называют с большой буквы (как у вас Main).
2. Желательно явно указывать модификатор доступа (`private` у Main отсутствует).
3. Стоит обрабатывать исключения при обработке пользовательского ввода, если
   используете `int.Parse()`, либо использовать `int.TryParse()`

Comment: 3. А стоит ли для явно игрушечного примера?

Comment: @VladD Длинная дорога начинается с небольшого шага. Я же не про TDD говорю, а про банальную стабильность.

Comment: Ну, скажем, так было бы чище, но при этом код был бы ужасен. Например, пришлось бы писать цикл запроса на повторение ввода при неправильном вводе, с возможностью дать пользователю выйти. Задача сразу стала бы тяжеловесной.

Comment: А можно про 3-й пункт подробнее? Пожалуйста.

Comment: @VladD Стоило бы выпилить интерактивность и просто работать с аргументами, как нормальное консольное приложение. Никаких бы циклов не понадобилось.

Comment: @Piston Да, пожалуйста) [int.Parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) и [int.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx). В доках есть примеры. Первый может бросить OverflowException, если в строке слишком большое для int число, и FormatException, если строку нельзя спарсить в число. Исключения нужно ловить. Второй же вариант возвращает bool значение успеха форматирования.

Comment: @free_ze Не очень понял. У меня в общем правильно?

Comment: @VladD Ну допустим [так](http://pastebin.com/pyUgj5Fq) код стал ужаснее?

Comment: @Piston Правильная программа не должна умирать в муках от неверного пользовательского ввода. Попробуйте, допустим, ввести слово вместо цифры.

Comment: Я пока не могу писать проверку ведённых символов.

Comment: @free_ze: Например, вам нужен альтернативный prompt, чтобы показать юзеру, что он ввёл неправильно — а то как он отличит случай неправильно введённого `x` от случая, когда `x` введён правильно, и следующая процедура вводит _новый_ `x`?

Comment: @VladD Глупо просить пользователя ввести некую "х" два раза подряд) Впрочем, [не вижу в этом проблемы](http://pastebin.com/HDpUjgYu)

Comment: @Piston Возьмите любой код из приведенных мной в этом треде. А еще лучше - попробуйте написать самостоятельно, а потом логику интерактивного меню в программе, это занимательно ;-)

Comment: @free_ze: А теперь посмотрите, насколько тяжелее получился код. В игрушечном примере акцент был на вычисления, у вас — на взаимодействие с пользователем.

Comment: @VladD Вы лукавите, здесь метод в очевидных 12 строк, которые можно легко копипастить из примера в пример) Да и странно, чтобы **интерактивная** программа не имела адекватной интерфейсной логики. Если бы использовались аргументы, то обойтись можно было бы одним if.

Comment: @free_ze: 12 строк, добавленных в программу из 14 строк, заметьте. И исходная программа прямолинейна как угол дома, ни циклов, ни даже ветвлений. А ваша программа уже довольно сложна для новичка. Она даже потребовала _абстракцию_: `GetNumber`. И разделяемую константу. Ваш код _намного_ сложнее.

Comment: @VladD Можно и без циклов - просто **корректно** выходить, а не валиться с непонятным эксешнном. Ничего сложного, просто if. Абстракции - это круто и правильно, тем более, что здесь она будет уже не первой и даже не второй ;-) А константа добавлена для красоты, она вовсе не обязательна.

Answer (score 1):

Мои пять копеек:

1. `Math.Pow` должен быть не вполне хорош для случая маленьких целых показателей степени, обычно советуют заменять его на прямое умножение.        `Math.Pow(a, 2)` при этом превращается просто в `a * a`, `Math.Pow(a, 3)` в `a * a * a`, для `Math.Pow(x, 4)` я бы завёл дополнительную переменную: `var xsquared = x * x`, и использовал выражение `xsquared * xsquared`.
2. Код

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("Enter please x: ");
   int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
   int answer = (int)(x * x + Math.Sin(x + 1)) / (x - 2);
   Console.WriteLine(answer);
   ```

   в начале `Main` выглядит слишком *отдельным*. На строчку ниже такой же код вынесен в отдельную процедуру. Я бы оформил этот код точно так же в виде отдельной процедуры.
3. Название процедур важно. Не называйте процедуры от фонаря, спросите себя, чего вы достигаете этой процедурой, и сделайте из этого название.
4. У вас напрасно стоит модификатор `public` во вложенных процедурах, ведь эти процедуры не рассчитаны на то, чтобы их вызывали снаружи. Впрочем, для маленьких, игрушечных программ, не работающих с классами, это не такая большая проблема, как мне кажется.

Я также поддерживаю замечание из [ответа @free_ze](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/527717/10105) насчёт правил именования: процедуры в C# принято называть в PascalCase: с большой буквы каждое слово, из которого составлено название.

Answer (score 0):

1. Все Ваши магические числа желательно выносить в отдельные переменные с адекватными названиями. Даже если сейчас Вам кажется, что вы этого никогда не забудете, то сделайте это для тех, кто будут ваш код читать в будущем (это касается не только этого примера, а вообще в целом).

   "Enter please x: " - можно тоже вынести.
2. У Вас, на мой взгляд, много ненужных приведений типа к int. Я бы посмотрел в сторону перехода к другому типу данных, например double.